# Word 2016 file displays lines (not borders) between paragraphs in Edit mode only - how to turn it off?

Tags: microsoft-word, troubleshooting, display-settings, microsoft-word-2016

A file created in 2010 and saved to 2016 now displays squiggly lines between every paragraph (see graphic).

[image: squiggly lines word 2016]

The lines display in Edit mode, whether working with a file created in a previous version or with a new 2016 file.

== Update ==
The lines do **not** appear in paper layout mode or when printed. Of course, in those modes, you can't do any editing. 
== End Update ==

I'm running 2010 and do not have the problem; I saw the problem via a video meeting; i.e., the other person was working in 2016 (a university version, mentioned here, in case that is of interest for the solution).

Via a screen share, I stepped through all of the Word Advanced Options to see if anything needed to be checked or unchecked, but saw nothing amiss.

What is going on? How can I advise the other person on how to fix it (make the lines go away)?

Comment: maybe this..http://www.howtogeek.com/217924/how-to-remove-automatic-horizontal-lines-in-word/

Comment: Regrettably, no. It's a temporary situation; i.e., the lines only appear in Edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It appears to MS Word 2016 now includes paragraphs when you click text boundaries (vs. in earlier versions when "text boundaries" was limited to margins.

If seeing the text boundaries of paragraphs annoys you, then rid the problem as follows:

To remove text boundaries:

1. Go to File > Options > Advanced.
2. Scroll down to the section "Show document content."
3. Uncheck "Show text boundaries."
4. Click OK.

As I recall, the StackExchange rules are that you cannot give your own answer an uptick. So if you are viewing this and it answers your question, please give an uptick so that others know the solution worked for more than just me.